# Comparing Lists and Deleting Duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using the following formula to test whether or not a single entry in one column exists in a second column:

```
=COUNTIF($E$1:$E$99504,$I1)>0
```

What I would like to be able to do is say that if the above formula evaluates to true, delete the duplicate entry from the second column (i.e. the duplicate in the E1-E99504 range), and shift the cells of this entry up.  I believe, aside from the cell shifting, this can be done without VBA.

However, I have 5 columns to compare in this particular case, with more possibly in the future.  As such I am trying to determine a way to perform the above operations on multiple columns using VBA.  Otherwise I would need to run the same process 10 times and I really feel like there is a more efficient way that I should learn.  The hierarchy of comparisons is as follows:

Suppose we have columns A,B,C,D,E.  A is compared to B, then to C, then to D, where each time duplicates in the unfixed columns are removed while the entries in A remain.  Then B is fixed, moving through C,D, and E in the same manner and again entries in B are preserved.  Similarly until D is compared to E and the process is complete.  Has someone already made an algorithm that does this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Deleting the cell **may** require **VBA**

Comment: you could create some metadata in the workbook by listing the columns to compare and direct your VBA code to that list. In your code you could search for a duplicate in any of the columns at once and avoid looping through the sheet x times (x = the number of columns to compare to).

Comment: you could also create a countif that only looks upward ( in this case `countif($E$1:$E1,$I1)>0`). If you do this for all x columns and take the max of them all, then you can filter on that and delete all filtered rows that are in violation...

Comment: @K_B Would you be able to elaborate on what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pure VBA solution and assuming your data looks like this:

[image]

I'd recommend working backwards since we are deleting and shifting data around.  Try this code:

```
Sub removeDuplicates()
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    lastCol = 5    'col 5 is column E

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Set searchRange = wks.Range("A1:A" & wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim compareArray As Variant
    Dim searchArray As Variant

    'Get all values from Col A to search against
    compareArray = searchRange.Value

    For col = lastCol - 1 To 1 Step -1
        'Set values to search for matches
        searchArray = searchRange.Offset(0, col - 1).Value

        'Set values to last column to compare against
        compareArray = searchRange.Offset(0, col).Value

        For i = 1 To UBound(compareArray)
            If compareArray(i, 1) = searchArray(i, 1) Then
                'Match found, delete and shift left
                Cells(i, col).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            End If
        Next i
    Next col
End Sub
```

---

Results:

[image]

---

Make sure you update the sheet name, range and last column number to match your criteria.

Comment: This is very helpful, my only question is why the shifts occur after the duplicates have been removed.  Wouldn't this introduce elements to a column that were not present in the column before?  Ideally I would only be removing elements and getting rid of the white space by moving the cell below the white space up.  As I think about it I suspect the reason is that my description was too ambiguous.

Comment: I assumed by the description that each row was it's own important data set.  So the code only matches, deletes and shifts data on a row by row basis.  Right now there is no logic between rows.  That would need another loop if I understand it correctly.  If you want more help, edit your post to include a sample before & after shot.

Comment: I think we are on the same page, the only difference being that each column is its own important data set.  However, it occurs to me that I could easily just transpose each column and this would work perfectly as long as I understand the macro correctly.  My other thought was that I could change the Shift:xlToLeft statement to Shift:xlUp, but if the rest of the code assumes row-based fields that may be an issue.  Thank you again for your help!  EDIT:  Upon further inspection the search range does seem to be column based as desired, so I may be unclear on the process used.

Comment: You would have to flip the loop to go bottom to top in order to shift upwards otherwise VBA wont know what to do when the next cell moved to a previous position (this is why I'm currently looping right to left).  Sounds like you understand it well.  Please mark as accepted if your content with the answer.  Thanks.